# Two objects in activity, modifying one automatically modifies the other

Tags: java, android-studio, object

In Android Studio I am writing an activity that lets the user modify a certain object called `product`. The user can also choose to save the made modifications. My goal is that when the user wants to leave the activity, and the modifications have not been saved yet, a notification is shown that tells the user that the modifications are not saved yet.

To achieve this, I have implemented the following steps:

1. In the `OnCreate` method, a copy of the object `product` is made, called `savedProduct`.
2. When the user modifies values, those changes are applied to `product`.
3. When the user saves the modifications, the values of `product` are stored in `savedProduct`.
4. When the user wants to leave the activity, the objects `product` and `savedProduct` are compared. When they differ, the user is notified.

The problem is that whenever a field in `product` is modified, those changes are automatically applied to `savedProduct`. That is a problem as they are now always equal and `savedProduct` does not hold the saved data anymore.

I think the problem lies in how `savedProduct` is initialized. Below are a few examples of how I tried to initialize `savedProduct`.

```
Product product, savedProduct;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitylayout);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        product = (Product) bundle.getSerializable("product");
        if (product != null) {
            savedProduct = product;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
Product product, savedProduct;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitylayout);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        product = (Product) bundle.getSerializable("product");
        if (product != null) {
            savedProduct = new Product(null,null);
            savedProduct.setName(product.getName());
            savedProduct.setPrice(product.getPrice());
        }
    }
}
```

When the user modifies values, the modifications are stored into `product` in the following way.

```
product.setName(nameEditText.getText().toString().trim());
product.setPrice(priceEditText.getText().toString().trim());
```

Comment: I don't see any references to `SavedProduct` in the code. Please make the question and the code consistent.

Comment: Oh that was a mistake, it is fixed now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do something like this:

```
productUpToDate = product;
```

You have to keep in mind that both variables are now just referencing the same object. When you modify one, it's going to modify the other. You could do something like this:

```
productUpToDate = (Product) SerializationUtils.clone(product);
```